# Manipulating Data Sets

Tags: discussion, support

Hello first time on this stack. I have a general question about where I can find data I can manipulate to just do some data visualization, or even parsing. I am using MS-DOS, Python, and GNUPlot just to create visuals of such data. Some of the data I have was based on measurements that involved like x was time, and y was output and then I could either take the derivative, or even plot it, and its derivative. Any help would be best, because right now I have been to several websites just to find data on Coronavirus being the header. Edit this is like a prescreen really.

Comment: wondering why this is on meta....this feels more like it should be an open question on open data se. that said, its pretty vague. i can point you to plenty of data portals that are full of datasets....if they are useful to you is another question.

Comment: @albert I am trying to craft a question about datasets that I can manipulate to use on Python, and Gnuplot.

Comment: @albert I found some from the Dept. of Agriculture.

Comment: which department of agriculture? have you tried data.gov or data.world?

Comment: @albert I shifted through some NSF open data links, and the US dept. of Agriculture I got a open dataset about CO, CO2 emission, and started scatter plots of those. I was also going to run some linear regressions on the data.